# Why can't I see a picklist field if I can apply it in my page layout?

Tags: permissions, salesforce, admin

my client requested that I update the values of a picklist field on the events object. This is something I've done in the past so I understand the process. However when I go to the fields and relationships tab of the object the picklist isn't there, even though it is used and visible in the page layout. is there a way to access this somewhere else or is this a permission issue?

as stated above, I have done this in the past so I'm familiar with the procedure. The field just isn't accessible on my or my superiors end, even though it is currently in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found that the custom fields for the "Events" tab are within the "Activities" object... I feel rather stupid. the issue has since been resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).